# Core Plot graph does not resize sometime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-plot

I have created a graph using core plot.
Graph is shown in on the screen perfectly.
i have a full screen button on tap on it a popOver shows the graph in a bigger frame...
The problem is that when i resize the graph sometime it does not resize..

If i dismiss the popover I can still see a big char on my screen. This does not happen all the time.

in my .h file

```
     CPGraphHostingView *scatterPlotView;
 CPXYGraph *graph, *barChart;
```

in my .m file

I have created the chart and now on the ful screen button click.

```
-(void)fullviewpressed:(id)sender
{


UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc]
                                    init];
UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc]
                       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 212, 1024, 480)];

if(!UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
    popoverView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 212, 768, 700);


popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
popoverContent.view = popoverView;


//resize the popover view shown
//in the current view to the view's size
popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(980, 460);

if(!UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))

    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(768-40, 660);

//create a popover controller
UIPopoverController * popoverController21 = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

self.popoverController = popoverController21;
[popoverController21 release];
self.popoverController.delegate = self;

CGRect btnRct = fullViewBtn.frame;
btnRct.origin.y+=20;

//present the popover view non-modal with a
//refrence to the button pressed within the current view

[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:btnRct
                                        inView:self.view
                      permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                      animated:YES];
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
    scatterPlotView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 10, 980, 460);
else
    scatterPlotView.frame  = CGRectMake(5, 10, 768-40, 660);
[popoverView addSubview:scatterPlotView];
    [touchView removeFromSuperview];
    touchView.frame =scatterPlotView.frame;
    [popoverView addSubview:touchView];
//release the popover content
   [popoverView release];
   [popoverContent release];
  }

 }
```

Here touchView is the object of UIView used to add annotation when user taps on the chart.

In short I am just changing the frame of my `CPGraphHostingView`.
but why it does not resize sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Core Plot are you using? Based on the "CP" class prefix in your code, I suspect it's pretty old. An update to a newer version might solve this problem for you.

Comment: I am using 0.3 version of coreplot and to suite my needs I have modified the coreplot classes..so I cannot just update to a newer version. I know its wrong to mess with the original files..

Comment: This problem is related to an issue that was fixed a while ago ( http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=281 ). Look at the revision linked from the issue report to see the changes you need to make in your copy to fix it.